# How do I control client-side caching?

Tags: php, apache, caching

We addressed the task of disabling client-side caching in “How do I prevent web browsers from caching a page?”, but disabling the cache is rarely the only (or best) option.

Here we’ll look at a mechanism that allows us to take advantage of client-side caches in a way that can be controlled from within a PHP script.

*Apache Required!
This approach will only work if you’re running PHP as an Apache web server module, because it requires use of the function getallheaders–which only works with Apache–to fetch the HTTP headers sent by a web browser.*

Comment: In what context? you can append ?r=randomnumber or for ajax you can pass headers, you need to be more specific.

Comment: Search for the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers and see how you can use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3rd result on google : https://encrypted.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=disable+cache+apache&btnG=Google+Search

The .htaccess method :

```
<FilesMatch ".(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

The PHP Method :

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

The jQuery/ajax Method:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

The Ghetto Method :

```
<a href="/path/page.php?r=random-number-generated-with-javascript-or-php">stuff</a>
```